# Checked property in input html for hiding content with css when blocks located differently

Tags: html, css, input

> The problem is - can I connect input with buttons in the way like in the code below or without changing html it's impossible (if I will not use js code for this).Do not scold the html code, this example is from one site, I'm just trying to figure out whether it is possible to access other blocks given nesting.

```
input:checked ~ button{
    display: none;
  }

<div  id="form">
    <section class="container">
        <form class="form">
            <section class="checkbox-control">
                <label for="personal-data-checkbox" class="checkbox-border">
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="personal-data-checkbox">
                </label>
                <label for="personal-data-checkbox" class="checkbox-label">
                    <span class="consent-message"></span>
                </label>
            </section>

            <section class="checkbox-control">
                <label for="cookie-checkbox" class="checkbox-border">
                    <input type="checkbox"  id="cookie-checkbox">
                </label>
                <label for="cookie--checkbox" class="checkbox-label">
                    <span> </span>
                </label>
            </section>

            <section class="buttons">
                <section class="confirm">
                    <button class="accept-all-button button">Agree to all</button>
                    <button class="confirm-button button hidden-button">Confirm</button>
                </section>
            </section>    
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**can I connect input with buttons**

No, you can't connect. As of now April 2020 there is no selector to select parent from child

However https://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational, This doc says they will include `:has()` selecor. Using which you can do it like

```
.checkbox-control:has(input:checked) ~ .buttons button {
      display: none;
}
```

But currently it is not supported

Comment: So, to solve this i can use js or i should change html?

Comment: @Gleb, It totally depends on you whichever suits you.... My opinion would be JS. As changing HTML for this requirement is not a good idea, As we also need to apply some CSS properties for which we need to wrap elements in a parent. So long story short, go with JS